# Compiler error running ootb web_ui sample

Tags: dart, dart-webui

i'm trying to compile the ootb web_ui sample. (Using Generate Sample Content - Web Application (using the web_ui library)

I have updated to latest editor `0.0.0_r18915` and have run pub update but am getting

```
Internal error:

'http://127.0.0.1:3030/C:/Users/me/dart/WebApplication/web/packages/logging/logging.dart':   
Error: line 250 pos 24: wrong number of type arguments in type 'Comparable'
class Level implements Comparable<Level> {

                   ^
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem here, and after some time, i've decided to pay attention at the stack trace... It says "Wrong number of type arguments in type 'Comparable'". Then, i just opened "logging.dart" and changed this:

```
class Level implements Comparable<Level> {
```

to this:

```
class Level implements Comparable {
```

Don't know if i did right, but worked fine for me. If someone knows the right way to do it, please, let us know ;)

Comment: I had this with the newest build as well. On a Macbook Pro 10.7 . Solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click Dart Editor (menu item) -> About Dart Editor.
2. Click the Download Update button.
3. After the update has downloaded, install/apply the update.
4. After the installation is complete, go to Tools (menu item) -> Pub Install.
5. Go to Tools (menu item) -> Pub Update.

After doing those five steps, I am able to compile the code.